# Manifest Theme error during adding Places API dependency

Tags: android, google-places-api, manifest

> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED
>   /home/ujjwal.anand/Documents/carpool/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:21:13-66 Error:
>       Attribute activity#com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity@theme value=(@style/PlacesAutocompleteThemeOverlay) from [com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:21:13-66
>       is also present at [com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:18:13-61 value=(@style/PlacesAutocompleteOverlay).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:16:9-23:20 to override.
>   /home/ujjwal.anand/Documents/carpool/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:22:13-71 Error:
>       Attribute activity#com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity@windowSoftInputMode value=(stateAlwaysVisible|adjustPan) from [com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:13-71
>       is also present at [com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:19:13-55 value=(adjustResize).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:windowSoftInputMode"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:16:9-23:20 to override.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

Comment: tools:replace="android:theme" to your app manifest

Comment: @Ujjwal got any answer?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. i solved it by removing 
`implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0'` from my build.gradle file. i was implementing the dependancy along side with `implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.1.0'` depending on what you want to do you have to choose the library you want to implement